# Read and play audio in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, audio, scipy, wav

I have some audio files on my computer. I want to do some analysis on them in Python3, part of which will include playing snippets of the audio files back.

I'm interested in AMR files. An example file is [here](http://cdn.online-convert.com/example-file/audio/amr/example.amr), but any file will do.

Here's my workflow so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import audioread
import numpy as np
fin = audioread.audio_open('test.amr') 
dat  = [x for x in fin]          #Generate list of bytestrings
dat  = b''.join(dat)             #Join bytestrings into a single urbytestring
ndat = np.fromstring(dat, '<i2') #Convert from audioread format to numbers

#Generate a wave file in memory
import scipy.io.wavfile
import io
memory_file = io.BytesIO() #Buffer to write to
scipy.io.wavfile.write(memory_file, fin.samplerate, ndat) 

#Play the wave file
import simpleaudio
wave_obj = simpleaudio.WaveObject(memory_file.getvalue())
play_obj = wave_obj.play()
play_obj.wait_done()
```

Problem is, when I go for the playback, I some very high-pitched, fast-sounding noise. I suspect a conversion's gone wrong somewhere, but am not sure where.

Trying to use `wave` produces similar results:

```
#Generate a wave file in memory using wave
import wave
import io
memory_file = io.BytesIO() #Buffer to write to
wave_file = wave.open(memory_file, 'w')
wave_file.setparams((fin.channels, 2, fin.samplerate, 0, 'NONE', 'not compressed'))
wave_file.writeframes(ndat.astype('<i2').tostring())
wave_file.close()
```

Both with and without the `astype`.

I suspected perhaps the audio backend used by `audioread` wasn't working, so I converted from AMR to WAV and then read in the file. That didn't fix things.

Writing the wave file to disk and playing with with a standard audio player did resolve things, so the problem seems to be `simpleaudio`.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out I was using `simpleaudio` incorrectly. The following works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import audioread
import numpy as np
fin  = audioread.audio_open('test_justin.amr') 
dat  = [x for x in fin]          #Generate list of bytestrings
dat  = b''.join(dat)             #Join bytestrings into a single urbytestring
ndat = np.fromstring(dat, '<i2') #Convert from audioread format to numbers

#Generate a wave file in memory
import scipy.io.wavfile
import io
memory_file = io.BytesIO() #Buffer to write to
scipy.io.wavfile.write(memory_file, fin.samplerate, ndat) 

#Play the wave file
import simpleaudio
wave_obj = simpleaudio.WaveObject.from_wave_file(memory_file)
play_obj = wave_obj.play()
play_obj.wait_done()
```

Comment: Brilliant! This code worked for me on Windows in an Anaconda environment too.